# Regression: Interpretation of decreasing slope with positive average growth

Tags: regression, trend

I have performed a linear fit on the following series using np.polyfit in python, where y is the net difference between inflow and outflow and x is month of year:

```
x   y
1   0
2   24
3   3
4   1
5   1
6   1
```

The regression equation comes out as:

```
y = -1.89x + 9.71
```

So this is saying that the overall slope of the line is decreasing with each unit increase in x. I can see this is being driven by one month having a spike in inflows (Month 2 = 24) and the rest of the months having minimal positive changes.

But, when we calculate the average of y, it comes out as 5 ((0+24+3+1+1+1)/6 = 5), which is saying on average you are gaining 5 each month, which again is being driven by that spike in month 2.

So my question is, what's a logical way of explaining a trend that is decreasing but has positive average unit growth? And the same goes for the opposite, when the slope of the equation is positive, but on average each month there is a net loss.

Comment: You’re confusing growth and changes in growth.  On average you are gaining each month.  The amount you gain each month decreases each month.

Comment: You are right, and that makes so complete sense. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have outlier which is significantly impacting your model. You need to decide how you are going to proceed. Below is a picture with added regression lines with and without the outlier. The difference is significant.

[image]